# Get DST/STD dates and times for a given timezone (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, windows-ce, dst

I am developping an embedded website contained within a windows CE device.
See it as if it was the web configuration interface of your router.
Everything is contained within a really small footprint of memory, the entire website is less than 500KB with every script, html, css and icons.

***We have to assume that the user that is going to 'browse' into that interface does not have access to the internet (LAN only) so no 'online' solution here.***

I am looking for a solution so the user choose his timezone and the code will  get all the DST/STD times and dates for the next 10-20 years at least and downloaded them to the device that will run autonomously after that and at specific dates, will change its time to DST/STD by itself. **Current application is custom (not windowce api related) and needs the DST/STD date pairs**.

iana.org is maintaining a db for like every location in the world. I also saw that moment-timezone (javascript interface) is 'packaging' this data in a very compact package 25kb zipped.

I need to know if it is possible to:

1. 'Extract' a main tz list from this DB so the user can choose its own tz. I looked at their doc but example didn't work:

`var itsTimeZones = moment.tz.names();`

2- Extract the next 10-20 years of DST/STD dates/times for a chosen zone ? I haven't saw any documentation anywhere on this topic. But since it's kind of the purpose of such a database, i would say it must be burried in there somewhere, need a way to dig it out.

3- If moment timezone is not the right track to go, anybody has a solution that will fullfill that requirement ?

Thanxs

Comment: Timezones change their offset occasionally, some regions change the rules for when daylight saving applies, some adopt it and some stop using it. Not all use a 1hr offset. You can only assume that the current daylight saving rules will apply for the future. You need a timezone database for offsets and when they apply, IANA is a good start, moment.js is likely a good solution (but not the only one).

Comment: Do you exclude the possibility to integrate a little c# program into your app? If not, Windows CE has already a list of timezones available

Comment: No C# comes with .net compact framework (or something of a kind) so really not realistic in our memory footprint.

Comment: What do you mean on #1 by "example didn't work"? I maintain moment-timezone, and it works fine, AFAIK.

Comment: Also, you do realize that even if we project 10-20 years of data based on the current rules - the rules themselves can change at any time and do change relatively often.  If you're asking to be future-proof, that is impossible.  Politicians will do as they will, we can only reflect their choices.

Comment: Another thing I'm confused on - Why are you wanting to have your application change the system's time?  This is usually a low-level system API, and Windows CE does indeed have time zone support, AFAIK.  Even if you could change the system time from your embedded web app (which I don't think is possible), you wouldn't because most system clocks are tracking UTC, not the local time.  You'd have to update the time zone data of the OS - which really should not be done through a web app either.

Comment: @ Matt, i was getting a browser error executing my script - obviously i did something wrong. The thing is, as 'cute' as the documentation of Moment-timezone can be, sometimes it is really hard to get what is the correct syntax (lack of code example) to do something and to understand the some concepts under it (when you haven't designed it).

Comment: @ Matt: For what is to be 'future-proof' i completely understand that moment-timezone will be re-released following future changes made by IANA and that is completely understandable.

Comment: @ Matt: Windows CE did had rules based on 2005. As you  know a CE platform is not 'Alive' as a workstation can be and doesn't get any updates on new 'rules'. Alot of our products are not even connected to the net (Mostly RS-485). In 2005 we choose to not use windows clock and implement our own 'sowftware' clock being THE reference (with external RTC to keeping time when powered off). Since DST info used to be provided by a software host with accurate info communicating with the devices, now making the device autonomus (no host), DST info has to come embedded into it.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for extracting DST list for a given zone from moment-timezone.
1. "theTz" is a numerical index from a change on a select in the webpage. 
2. select is populated with "List".

```
var itsTz =
{
    "List" : moment.tz.names(), // Get all zone 'Names'
    "Transitions" : [],
};


function TimeZoneChanged(theTz)
{
    var myZone = moment.tz.zone(itsTz.List[theTz]);  // Get zone by its name from List
    var myTime = moment.tz(moment(), myZone.name);   // Start today
    var myResult;

    // Build transition list according to new zone selected
    itsTz.Transitions = [];
    do
    {
        myResult = GetNextTransition(myZone, myTime);

        if(myResult != null)
        {
            itsTz.Transitions.push(moment(myResult).format("YYYY/MM/DD"));
            myTime = moment.tz(myResult, myZone.name);  // Get next from date found
        }
    }while(myResult != null);
}

function GetNextTransition(theZone, theTime)
{
    var myResult;

    for(var i = 0; i < theZone.untils.length; i++) 
    {
        if(theZone.untils[i] > theTime) 
        {
            theZone.untils[i] == Infinity ? myResult = null : myResult = new moment(theZone.untils[i]).format();
            return  myResult;
        }
    }
}
```

Results for 'America/Toronto:

2017/03/12,
2017/11/05,
2018/03/11,
2018/11/04,
2019/03/10,
2019/11/03,
2020/03/08,
2020/11/01,
2021/03/14,
2021/11/07,
2022/03/13,
2022/11/06,
2023/03/12,
2023/11/05,
2024/03/10,
2024/11/03,
2025/03/09,
2025/11/02,
2026/03/08,
2026/11/01,
2027/03/14,
2027/11/07,
2028/03/12,
2028/11/05,
2029/03/11,
2029/11/04,
2030/03/10,
2030/11/03,
2031/03/09,
2031/11/02,
2032/03/14,
2032/11/07,
2033/03/13,
2033/11/06,
2034/03/12,
2034/11/05,
2035/03/11,
2035/11/04,
2036/03/09,
2036/11/02,
2037/03/08,
2037/11/01,

Comment: Results for 'America/Toronto: